# Why vlookup function code does not work, why?

Tags: excel, vba

My code is not working it gives N/A

Vlookup on vba

```
    Dim ws As Worksheet

     Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Loaded_Plan")

     With ws
         .Range("K4:K523").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(C4:C523,Volumes!$C6:$M118,5,0)"


    End With

End Sub
```

expected result is that it gives the volumes

**EDIT**: Here is the worksheet with the VLOOKUP in column K.

[image]

Comment: I don't see how column C on the "Loaded_Plan" sheet matches the format of column C on the "Volumes" tab.

Comment: maybe not for the fist lines but other lines down it matches

Comment: It has to match exactly. i.e. "foo" on one sheet and "foo" on the other. It doesn't seem like that is the scenario here.

Comment: I see what I said is that it matches for other lines  after but even for those it didn't work , is there any other function like to check if it includes some letters or number.?

Comment: Yes but at this point it's probably better to ask a new question about that, providing some sample (fake) data for both the lookup value and the column you look up in.

Comment: @BigBen but is it okey for the code , why it is not working for other articles ?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean, but would suggest you ask a new question. That will be the best way to help you.

Comment: @BigBen  I have an other question related to the first one , now the code is working but doesn't work for all the articles , even I cheked an example and I saw that we have the same part description , same everything but it didn't work , the code is here :                                                                                                             Range("K4:K400").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(Z4,Volumes!$B$6:$M$118,6,0)"
      '.Range("K4:K523").Formula ="=VLOOKUP(Z4:Z523,Volumes!$C6:$M118,5,0)"
     .Range("M4:M400").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(Z4,Volumes!$B$6:$M$118,7,0)"

Comment: Why do you have `Z4:Z523` as the lookup value in one of those lines.? Just `Z4`.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need the entire range `C4:C523` as the lookup value.

Just keep `C4` and since it has relative references, Excel will update to `C5` all the way down to `C523` for each row.

```
.Range("K4:K523").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(C4,Volumes!$C6:$M118,5,0)"
```

Comment: Hello I've tried but still give me the same problem N/A

Comment: @yassmineidrissi `#N/A` means the lookup isn't finding the value in the lookup range. Make sure the values in column C exist in `Volumes!C:C` - we cannot guess why the lookup isn't working without seeing your data though.

Comment: they are :/ BUT it doesn't work , can I have your email @Mathieu Guindon

Comment: @yassmineidrissi instead of asking for an email (which probably won't be shared), perhaps edit your question with some sample data or a screenshot. Or test that the lookup value is the same as the value in your list (i.e. ensure there's no trailing space, or mismatch like date vs. text). The fact that the formula returns `#N/A` has nothing to do with VBA at this point.